# Internal server error in Google Composer web UI [Error code 28]

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are using Google Composer for workflow orchestration, randomly we are getting `An internal server error occurred while authorizing your request. Error code 28` message while opening the web UI. We don't know the cause for this issue. How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This issue could be given for users who try to access Airflow UI from certain location. Notice that direct access to the Airflow UI is not supported in Australia, New Zealand, and India as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface#proxying_airflow_webserver_access). The product team is working on the resolution. At this moment, the users from these location can [use HTTP proxy](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface#proxying_airflow_webserver_access) for that.

Comment: We are fully aware of this issue and working on a permanent fix, ETA: end of Q1 2019.

Comment: It's currently Q3 2020 and this is still an issue

Comment: We are also experiencing this issue in the USA, Q3 2020

Comment: Same here from Japan. I don't know this is related to the original SO question. I think this is not an issue related to the region.